# How to Include Jquery function in a partial view in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a jquery button click method which works fine in views other than modals.uploadbtn button click method doesn't work when partial view is loaded in the modals

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />
            <input id="documentType" name="entity" value=@ViewData["entity"] hidden>
            <input id="id" name="id" value=@Model hidden>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload" />
            <button type="button" id="uploadbtn">Upload</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#uploadbtn").click(function () {
            console.log("came");
            var documentType = $('#documentType').val();
            var fileUpload = $("#files").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;
            console.log(files);


          

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Can someone tell me what I should do in order to get this working in the modals?
I am working in a .net core project

Comment: Do you mean Upload appears after you click on Modal?

Comment: Not addressing your specific issue, but in general, it's not advisable to include scripts in partial views. It will load your script multiple times whenever the modal/partial view is called, which in turn, can lead to unexpected results, e.g.., functions being called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**  Demo as below:

Controller.cs: I create an action `BBB` to return `_FilePartialView`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
   {
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult BBB()
        {
            return PartialView("_FilePartialView");
        }
    }
```

In privacy view, I add a modal to upload file.

```
<button id="btnShowModal" type="button" > Upload </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal">                                            
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button  id="btnHideModal" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">  ×</button>
      </div>                                                             
    <div class="modal-body" >
</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
                $.get("@Url.Action("BBB","Home")",
                function(data){$('.modal-body').html(data);})
                $("#Modal").modal('show'); 
            });
        $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#Modal").modal('hide');
            });
        });       
    </script>
```

_FilePartialView.cshtml:

`[Note]`I remove  `<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: When I add my partial view to modal, jquery functions related to partial view (uploadbtn button click event) are not working. It only happens inside the modals

Comment: You need to remove your js outside partial view,and put them into the page which contains partial view.

Comment: @Oshadhi, refer to the detailed code I have changed, and if you still have problems, can you  post how you added partial view to modal? And  you can set breakpoints or use F12 to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @QingGuo In my case there is a button that opens up a modal, in that modal, there is another button that opens up another modal, in that modal file upload partial view is displayed. but in the second modal jquery doesn't' work.but , in the first modal jquery works

Comment: @Oshadhi  Can you share your code about second Modal?

Comment: @Oshadhi  In your another Modal which way you use to load partial view?

Comment: @QingGuo it looks like jquery is not loaded in the second modal. I created a new project and did the same scenario. but in that jquery works properly. I used the same code.

Comment: It happened because the partial view loaded twice on the page. The button click method only worked for one view.Thanks for your support @QingGuo